# What datatype should I use to save p-values in a mysql database?

Tags: mysql, sqldatatypes, p-value

I am slightly confused what datatype in mysql can handle p-values. My toy dataset p-values range from 8.11E-247 to 0.099940924.

Comment: You generally want a precision column (`DECIMAL`) but such precision is limited to 65 total digits: clearly not enough for your miniscule value. Use text to hold a literal value, then perform calculations in your app.

Comment: Makes sense. Thanks!

Comment: Are you really need to store ~240 digits accuracy? The Universe has diameter about 8.60908085e26 meters, so your accuracy points to size 1e-100 meters, while Plank's length is about 1e-35 meters. I know nothing about the nature of your data, but it looks like huge overhead.

Comment: Yeah, you can probably safely call 8.11E-247 a zero, even in academia.

Comment: What is a "p-value"?

Answer (score 2):

Use [`DOUBLE`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/floating-point-types.html) type, which can hold up to `E±308`